# Text is no copying by clipboard.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, copy, clipboard.js

I'm trying to copy text using clipboard.js but it's not copying.
here's my code

```
$(document).ready(async function () {
    var html = ''
    var script = '<script>'
    let response = await ajax('/admin/all_files', 'POST', '')
    for (let i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
        var url = window.location.origin + '/get_file/' + response[i][0]
        html += `<div>
                <img src="`+ url +`" alt="">
                <div>
                    <button  id="ttc_`+ i +`_url" data-clipboard-text=`+ url +`>URL</button>
                </div>
            </div>`
        script += `var ttc_`+ i +`_url = new Clipboard('#ttc_`+ i +`_url');`
    }
    $('#insert_image_modal_body').html(html)
    script += '</script>'
    $('body').append(script)
})
```

my ajax function is:

```
async function ajax(url, method, data) {
    return $.ajax({
        url: window.location.origin + url,
        method: method,
        data: data
    }).done((response) => {
        return response
    });
}
```

it shows nothing, no error but the text is not copying too.

Comment: Don't you have an error like `ajax is not defined` in console? - `let response = await ajax(...` should be `let response = await $.ajax(...`

Comment: Better use `.done()` instead of `await` with jQuery.... Here is you code sligthly updated on [codepen](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/BaVojgK?editors=1011) (using a different ajax url)

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette I've updated the question, I've included the ajax function too.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Couple of things, I noticed in some areas you were using `var` when you could've been using `let` or `const` (as of ES6). Here's a good article that will describe the differences for you: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/var-let-and-const-whats-the-difference/

Secondly, your code seems to generate javascript, within javascript... it's possible what you're doing, but might as well just do what you're doing within the *existing* script tags that you already have.

Thirdly, you are attempting to use template literals to form you strings. That's great, however you aren't leveraging the most important part, and that's the ability to inject values directly into the string using the `${}` notation.

Regarding the clipboard code. Since you are utilizing `data-clipboard-text` there's no need to require each button to have a unique id. Instead you can add a class, for example `copy-btn` that you add to each button. This way you only have to call `new ClipboardJS('.copy-btn');` once!

Taking all of these into consideration, I've cleaned up your code a bit below:

```
$(document).ready(async function () {
        let html = '';
        const response = await ajax('/admin/all_files', 'POST', '');
        for (let i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
            const url = window.location.origin + '/get_file/' + response[i][0];
            html += `
                <div>
                    <img src='${url}' />
                    <div>
                        <button class='copy-btn' data-clipboard-text='${url}'>URL</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            `;
        }
        $('#insert_image_modal_body').html(html);
        new ClipboardJS('.copy-btn');
});
```

Comment: I've applied events to check, I got them from the docs (https://clipboardjs.com/). It shows success but the text is not copied.

Comment: You shouldn't need to use events. The code I posted above should work.

Comment: I insert HTML in the bootstrap modal, when I use a single div in a body, it works.
Thanks brother 

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is due to bootstrap modals, I was adding data to the modal. Adding data to a single div outside the modal and using the append function instead of HTML solved my problem.

Now my code is

```
let html = '';
    const response = await ajax('/admin/all_files', 'POST', '');
    for (let i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
        const url = window.location.origin + '/get_file/' + response[i][0];
        html += `
            <div style="border-radius: 9px; border: 1px solid #000; height: 150px;" class="col-1 col m-1 p-1 d-flex flex-column align-items-center">
                <img style="height: 100px; width: auto; max-width:100%" src='${url}' alt="" />
                <div class="row m-0 my-1 p-0 justify-content-center">
                    <button style="width: 45%;" class="mx-1 btn btn-sm btn-outline-success clipboard" data-clipboard-action='copy' data-clipboard-text='${url}'>URL</button>
                    <button style="width: 37%;" class="mx-1 btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary clipboard" data-clipboard-text='Hi 2'>Alt</button>
                </div>
            </div>`;
    }
    $('#insert_image_box_body').append(html);
```